How to clear stored data on new release for iOS and android using flutter?
I'm using Flutter to release an app on both the App Store (Apple) and Play Store (Android)and I store some data using SharedPreferences.
In the latest versions of iOS and Android, the data from the previous app version is cached. When users update the application, they still get the old stored files.
I want the new app version to be installed as if it were the first time, without carrying over any old data.
My questions are:

How can I achieve this using Flutter for both platforms (Apple and Android)?
Is there a way to do this using the Google Play Console and the Apple Developer Console?

Note: I'm not using a local database, only SharedPreferences.
My project dependencies are:
dependencies:
  badges: ^3.1.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  card_swiper: ^3.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  dio: ^5.3.2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.3
  file_picker: ^8.0.3 #revisar
  firebase_analytics: ^11.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.1
  firebase_core: ^3.1.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^4.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^15.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_hooks: ^0.20.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_modular: ^6.0.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0 
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.5.1
  http_parser: ^4.0.2
  image_picker: ^1.0.4 
  intl: any
  logger: ^2.0.2+1
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.7.0
  package_info_plus: ^8.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.1
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  stack_trace: ^1.11.1 
  upgrader: ^10.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12 

I tried to search in the internet but did not find something really useful, maybe I did not searched for it very well.
I thought of doing something using the upgrader package, since it have some functions that compare the older and newer versions.

Add something that can be identified, such as a version to your preference data.
You can now check the version of preference data in your app and if there is an old version of the data, you can delete the preference data with the following code.
...
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
...
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.clear();
...

if your data has a particular key value, you can try this:
...
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; 
...
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.remove('//PUT//YOUR//KEY//HERE//');
...

